# Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client - Multiple Profiles

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, cisco-vpn-client

I'm using `Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client (3.1.05187)` on my `MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013)` using `OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 (14D136)`.

I use multiple `VPN Server` and whenever I switch to another `VPN Server`, `Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client` does *NOT* retain my previous `VPN Server` in drop-down.

Please advise.

Comment: Is it same the case if you quit and relaunch AnyConnect GUI ?

Comment: It's always the case( I need multi profile setup..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `win32` - `C:\Users\<you>\AppData\Local\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\Profile`
- `mac` - `/opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile/`

Create an XML file with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AnyConnectProfile xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/encoding/"> 
<ServerList> 
     <HostEntry>
          <HostName></HostName>
          <HostAddress></HostAddress>
     </HostEntry>
     <HostEntry>
          <HostName></HostName>
          <HostAddress></HostAddress>
     </HostEntry>
</ServerList>
</AnyConnectProfile>
```

Comment: my mac doesn't have c:\ drive, what is xml profile location in regards to `osx`?

Comment: check under /opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile

Comment: what's filename for new xml? (I have one xml in there already `/opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile/AnyConnectProfile.xsd` in that xml location)

Comment: that's an XSD file you typed.. just create an xml. I use work.xml on my work pc and poop.xml at home.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to include `Username` into that `.XML` as well?

Comment: <User>yourusername</User> under <HostEntry>

Comment: I tried that, however that did not working for me( Where are you getting that information from? can you include that into your question please?

Comment: I've been writing them by hand for a couple years now, i just pulled it from my .xml. i believe i originally used the profile creator cisco makes to figure out how to do it...

Comment: hmm, I wonder why this isn't working for me... would you mind to pastebin yours? mask sensitive info, of course)

Comment: I know it's been a minute, but i wanted to add, the admin can prevent storing the username serverside. this could be why it isn't working for you (in terms of username)

Comment: '15 - a minute, really?)

Comment: :) as long as these questions and answers are searchable, they should be relevant :P  I added the note because last week, i added a client profile to my anyconnect and could not save the username; this made me think of this posting.

Comment: so uh.. so no time traveling machine? that's a bummer man...

Comment: Now I just want to know how to set the default value. The first apparently doesn't do it.

Comment: Using OSX 10.14.6 I gave up on this and then had a hell of a time uninstalling the software and reinstalling it (btw not necessary to enter a new profile, but see http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/mitcontrib/Cisco+Anyconnect+Manual+uninstall+Mac+OS). Key info for me was "user preferences is a file in /Users/username/.anyconnect" https://community.cisco.com/t5/vpn/how-to-install-xml-profiles-for-anyconnect-for-mac/td-p/2349880